# scalogram shows black image

Tags: python, wavelet

my goal is to generate  scalogram from .wav file and  save  as jpg or png format,i used following code :

```
import cv2
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import pywt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
y,sr =librosa.load("genres_original/classical/classical.00000.wav")
print(sr)
width =np.arange(1,31)
# cwtmatr =signal.cwt(y,signal.gau,width)
coef, freqs=pywt.cwt(y,width,'morl')
print(coef)
# plt.imshow(abs(cwtmatr), cmap='plasma', aspect='auto')
# plt.matshow(abs(coef))
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.imshow(abs(coef), extent=(0, 200, 30, 1), interpolation='bilinear', cmap='bone',
           aspect='auto', vmax=abs(coef).max(), vmin=abs(coef).max())
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 31, 1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 31, 1))
plt.show()
           # vmax=abs(cwtmatr).max(),
           # vmin=-abs(cwtmatr).min()) # finally we plot the scalogram
```

but when i am running this code, getting blanck image
[image]

could you tell me please what is reason? what part  am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to run your example locally but try something like this using [plt.pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) :

```
    t=np.arange(len(INPUTSIGNAL))
    plt.pcolormesh(t, freqs, np.abs(coefs), shading='auto')
    plt.yticks(np.arange(min(freqs), max(freqs)+1, 3))
    plt.margins(x=0)
```

I've only used plt.imshow with real images so I don't know if that function is making some assumptions on what it will receive as an input. To plot a scalogram plt.pcolormesh can do the job pretty quickly.